# Unable to send request to Google Cloud Compute Engine with Service Account credentials

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, service-accounts, google-vpc

I have a VM set up running a container with an in memory database (with redis). I know this is already a google service, but it is a lot cheaper for me to host it myself on a VM. I set up a VPC Firewall rule to allow traffic into the VM on port 8000 with a service account, open on 0.0.0.0/0 ipv4. I assume that this means it will accept traffic from all IPs as long as they have the correct credentials.

The issue is that no matter how I send the request packet I cannot get a response with the credentials. I always get `ReadTimeout`.

```
    raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host=(PUBLIC_IP), port=8000): Read timed out. (read timeout=2)
```

This is the code that I'm using for the request, the exact same thing can successfully connect to Cloud Run services and Cloud Functions, but maybe not here?

```py
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession


KEY_FILE = 'vm-key.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']

ip = # IP
port = 8000

target_audience = f"https://{ip}:{port}"
url = f"{target_audience}/get_attributes"

creds = service_account.IDTokenCredentials.from_service_account_file(
    KEY_FILE,
    target_audience=target_audience)
authed_session = AuthorizedSession(creds)

uuids = [
    ... payload
]

response = authed_session.post(url=url, json=uuids, verify=False, timeout=2)
```

I have tried connecting without the service account rule, ie accepting traffic from 0.0.0.0/0 and it works exactly as expected, the ports are open and talking to the container. It's only when I try to make the connection with the service account. I have tried using `target_audience = f"http://{ip}:{port}"` (http not https), a whole set of different target audiences in case it is wrong, but nothing I have tried has made any difference.

It seems like a super simple problem and I've been stuck on it for hours, so if anyone has any insights I'd appreciate it a lot.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you select the correct service account when you set your firewall rule?

Comment: Yes, I have made sure that it's correct, and I've tried a few different service accounts with different levels of permissions - none of them worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to confirm that you can connect via IP:Port connection, I think the issue is more on the code. As per error suggested, try configuring the read timeout of the code. In some case, there is a certain part of your script that makes the server unable or do not know what response should be.